# ERROR: command errored out with exit status 1 when installing Kivy

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, kivy

I am trying to install Kivy by using: pip3 install Kivy and I keep getting this error `ERROR: command errored out with exit status 1`
My pip is up to date and I tried installing the library via PyCharm and via the Terminal (I am using a mac). Thanks in advance
added the error below

```
Collecting Kivy
  Using cached Kivy-1.11.1.tar.gz (23.6 MB)

DEPRECATION: The -b/--build/--build-dir/--build-directory option is deprecated. pip 20.3 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is use the TMPDIR/TEMP/TMP environment variable, possibly combined with --no-clean. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8333.
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/davidsokulin/PycharmProjects/FirsProject/venv/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/ch/_69bcffn79s9nxnc5mzrsm4r0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/kivy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/ch/_69bcffn79s9nxnc5mzrsm4r0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/kivy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/ch/_69bcffn79s9nxnc5mzrsm4r0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-m9a_f9np
         cwd: /private/var/folders/ch/_69bcffn79s9nxnc5mzrsm4r0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/kivy/
    Complete output (92 lines):
    Using setuptools
    User distribution detected, avoid portable command.
    Using this graphics system: OpenGL ES 2
    OSX framework used, force to x86_64 only
    OSX ARCHFLAGS are: -arch x86_64
    GStreamer framework not found, fallback on pkg-config
    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 127)
    
    b'/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found\n'
    
    Missing framework /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework
    Missing framework /Library/Frameworks/SDL2_ttf.framework
    Missing framework /Library/Frameworks/SDL2_image.framework
    Missing framework /Library/Frameworks/SDL2_mixer.framework
    SDL2 frameworks not found, fallback on pkg-config
    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_image SDL2_mixer (code 127)
    
    b'/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found\n'
    
    Xcode detected at b'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer', and using OS X10.15 sdk
    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags pangoft2 (code 127)
    
    b'/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found\n'
    
    ERROR: Dependency for context.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for compiler.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for context_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for fbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for gl_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for opengl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for opengl_utils.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for shader.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for stencil_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for scissor_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for texture.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vertex.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vertex_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_mock.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_gl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_glew.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_sdl2.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for svg.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
     WARNING: The wheel package is not available.
    WARNING: Skipping page https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden/archive/master.zip because the HEAD request got Content-Type: application/zip.The only supported Content-Type is text/html
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /Users/davidsokulin/PycharmProjects/FirsProject/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/ch/_69bcffn79s9nxnc5mzrsm4r0000gn/T/pip-wheel-ijxakt66/cython/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/ch/_69bcffn79s9nxnc5mzrsm4r0000gn/T/pip-wheel-ijxakt66/cython/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/ch/_69bcffn79s9nxnc5mzrsm4r0000gn/T/pip-wheel-oan20jxf
           cwd: /private/var/folders/ch/_69bcffn79s9nxnc5mzrsm4r0000gn/T/pip-wheel-ijxakt66/cython/
      Complete output (7 lines):
      Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.
      usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
         or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
         or: setup.py --help-commands
         or: setup.py cmd --help
    
      error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for cython
    ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "/Users/davidsokulin/PycharmProjects/FirsProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 126, in fetch_build_egg
         subprocess.check_call(cmd)
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
         raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
     subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/Users/davidsokulin/PycharmProjects/FirsProject/venv/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/var/folders/ch/_69bcffn79s9nxnc5mzrsm4r0000gn/T/tmp25x0n6e6', '--quiet', '--find-links', 'https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden/archive/master.zip', 'cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.10,>=0.24']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    
     The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
       File "/private/var/folders/ch/_69bcffn79s9nxnc5mzrsm4r0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/kivy/setup.py", line 1073, in <module>
         setup(
       File "/Users/davidsokulin/PycharmProjects/FirsProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 152, in setup
         _install_setup_requires(attrs)
       File "/Users/davidsokulin/PycharmProjects/FirsProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 147, in _install_setup_requires
         dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
       File "/Users/davidsokulin/PycharmProjects/FirsProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 673, in fetch_build_eggs
         resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
       File "/Users/davidsokulin/PycharmProjects/FirsProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 764, in resolve
         dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
       File "/Users/davidsokulin/PycharmProjects/FirsProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1049, in best_match
         return self.obtain(req, installer)
       File "/Users/davidsokulin/PycharmProjects/FirsProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1061, in obtain
         return installer(requirement)
       File "/Users/davidsokulin/PycharmProjects/FirsProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 732, in fetch_build_egg
         return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
       File "/Users/davidsokulin/PycharmProjects/FirsProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 128, in fetch_build_egg
         raise DistutilsError(str(e)) from e
     distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['/Users/davidsokulin/PycharmProjects/FirsProject/venv/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/var/folders/ch/_69bcffn79s9nxnc5mzrsm4r0000gn/T/tmp25x0n6e6', '--quiet', '--find-links', 'https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden/archive/master.zip', 'cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.10,>=0.24']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you miss `pkg-config`, try with

```
brew install pkg-config
```

Comment: also check `which pkg-config` and try to add it into path `export PKG_CONFIG=/path/to/pkg-config`